# Pytorch: Test each row of the first 2D tensor also exist in the second tensor?

Tags: arrays, numpy, pytorch, tensor, isin

Given two tensors `t1` and `t2`:

```
t1=torch.tensor([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
t2=torch.tensor([[1,2],[5,6]])
```

If the row elements of `t1` is exist in `t2`, return `True`, otherwise return `False`. The ideal result is
`[Ture, False, True]`.
I tried `torch.isin(t1, t2)`, but its return the results by elements not by rows. By the way, if they are numpy arrays, it can be completed by

```
np.in1d(t1.view('i,i').reshape(-1), t2.view('i,i').reshape(-1))
```

I wonder how to get the similar result in tensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def rowwise_in(a,b):
  """ 
  a - tensor of size a0,c
  b - tensor of size b0,c
  returns - tensor of size a1 with 1 for each row of a in b, 0 otherwise
  """
  
  # dimensions
  a0 = a.shape[0]
  b0 = b.shape[0]
  c  = a.shape[1]
  assert c == b.shape[1] , "Tensors must have same number of columns"

  a_expand = a.unsqueeze(1).expand(a0,b0,c)
  b_expand = b.unsqueeze(0).expand(a0,b0,c)

  # element-wise equality
  equal = a_expand == b_expand

  # sum along dim 2 (all elements along this dimension must be true for the summed dimension to be True)
  row_equal = torch.prod(equal,dim = 2)

  row_in_b = torch.max(row_equal, dim = 1)[0]
  return row_in_b
```

Comment: For two large tensors, the `torch.prod` returns error: `RunTime Error : cuda out of memory.` with my GPU. I modified it as `row_equal = torch.logical_and(equal[:,:,0],equal[:,:,1])`. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the greate solution of [DerekG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9831777/derekg) this small change seems more fast and robust

```
a,b = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7]],device=torch.device(0)), torch.tensor([[1,2,3],[5,6,7]],device=torch.device(0))
# dimensions
shape1 = a.shape[0]
shape2 = b.shape[0]
c  = a.shape[1]
assert c == b.shape[1] , "Tensors must have same number of columns"

a_expand = a.unsqueeze(1).expand(-1,shape2,c)
b_expand = b.unsqueeze(0).expand(shape1,-1,c)
# element-wise equality
mask = (a_expand == b_expand).all(-1).any(-1)
```

I tried that for tensors with 10 000 rows, it works pretty fast and  without memory wasting